# Always show thumb in ScrollViewer scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

How can I get the scrollbars of the `ScrollViewer` control to always show the scrollbar thumbs, with the thumbs at maximum length if the `ScrollViewer`'s contents is smaller than the available area?

Take the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid Height="300" Width="300" Background="Red">

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Resizing the window to smaller than the 300x300 pixel grid will make the thumbs in both the horizontal and vertical scrollbars appear.

[image]

But when increasing the window size to larger than the 300x300 pixel grid, both horizontal and vertical scrollbar thumbs are gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> always show the scrollbar thumbs

One possibility is to subscribe to `Track` (that is the part which you click and which is hidden ) `IsVisibilityChanged` event and force show it:

```
HackTheTrack(scrollViewer.FindChildren<Track>().First());
HackTheTrack(scrollViewer.FindChildren<Track>().Skip(1).Single()); // second track

void HackTheTrack(Track track)
{
    track.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    track.IsVisibleChanged += (s, ee) =>
    {
        if (track.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
            track.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    };
}
```

You will need this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildren<T>(this DependencyObject @this) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (@this == null)
        yield break;
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(@this); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(@this, i);
        var result = child as T;
        if (result != null)
            yield return result;
        foreach (var value in FindChildren<T>(child))
            yield return value;
    }
    yield break;
}
```

But the appearance of this is pretty confusing:

---

[image]

---

Comment: Interesting approach.  While the thumbs *are* visible, they aren't resized to fill the entire track.  But perhaps I need to override the method that calculates the size of the thumb, both to avoid the thumb being set to false, but also to recalculate the size of the thumb to fill the entire track.